# How to check if call was ended by the user or automatically?

Tags: java, android, call, phone-state-listener

I would like to know if there is a way to ckeck if incoming call was ended by the user (dropped) or ended automatically because there wasn't a response (missed call). In other words: I want to do some action the moment when there appears a missed call (when the call is ended automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Do Something like that when missed call is appeared. In my code i open activity when missed call appeared.

```
switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.v("idle state", "CALL_STATE_IDLE");

        // CALL_STATE_IDLE ( OpenMissedCallScreen )


        if (ring == true && callReceived == false && CheckMissCall.isRunning== false) {



            flag = true;
            if (prefs.getBoolean("main_state", true))
            {
                Intent inter = new Intent(c, MissCall.class);

            }

        }



        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

        // CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK ( OpenReceivedCallScreen )
        callReceived = true;



        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

        ring = true;
        // CALL_STATE_RINGING ( openIncomingCallScreen )


        break;
```